# Cant keep interfaces in assigned zones, Centos7

Tags: centos7, firewalld

I came across to some strange behavior of Firewalls
having 3 interfaces and when using permanent assignment rule for interface to zone

after reboot it jumps back to the default zone 
(which ever is set as default zone in firewalld)

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-interface=eno16777736
```

or

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --change-interface=eno16777736
```

they aren't seem to be working ....

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug, you may'd like to visit : https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7526

I found only one way to fix this at this time

```
echo "ZONE=what_ever_zone_youd_like" >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno16777736

firewall-cmd --complete-reload
systemctl restart firewalld.service
```

then check it

```
firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
```

Comment: This is not a bug, just normal behavior that some CentOS users were not aware of. NetworkManager decides what firewall zone is to be used for interfaces it manages.

Comment: how can NetworkManager decide where I need it to be if let say I'm trying to create loadbalancing...

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve a similar issue with FirewallD, NetworkManager and Docker in CentOS 7.

It seems to be an issue in FirewallD, I reported it here, with a workaround solution to make it work after a reboot: https://github.com/t-woerner/firewalld/issues/195

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problems before. In our infrastructure we've realized that sometimes without no reason `NetworkManager` was putting out of the defined zone some interfaces. (Till that moment we configured zones in interfaces configuration files)

As it obvious, in a production environment this is just UNACCEPTABLE.

How we manage to solve this problem :

1. Disable NetworkManager
2. Configure de interface zone in the zone file under `/etc/firewalld/zones/*.xml`
3. The syntax is as it follows :

   ```
   <interface name="<interface_name>"/>
   ```
4. You'll be able now to `restart` / `reload` firewalld without any troubles

Otherwise, I suspect that if you set up your zone with the command below and with `Networkmanager` disabled and not running it will work just fine

```
firewall-cmd --zone=<zone_name> --change-interface=<interface_name> --permanent
```

Comment: Actually, I've just tested after executing an update, and the bug in `Networkmanager` that was causing this behavior seams to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

When the system is using **NetworkManager** to handle interface configuration (as may be indicated by empty or missing `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*` directory entries), try the following steps to set the zone via NetworkManager's configuration system:

1. verify NetworkManager is running: `systemctl status NetworkManager`

```
$ systemctl status NetworkManager

● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running)
```

2. if so, list the connection *"profile name"* (which may differ from *device* names) by using: `nmcli`

```
$ nmcli

                   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv "profile name"
eth0: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Red Hat Virtio"
        ethernet (virtio_net),
```

3. set the desired "ZONE" with `nmcli` using the profile name, example:

```
$ nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 1" connection.zone ZONE
```

The zone change should be immediately visible via `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` and persist across future reboots.