# firewalld: interface autonomously changing zones

Tags: docker, firewalld, rhel8

I have an RHEL8 system serving as a Docker Swarm worker node. It has `firewalld` enabled, and has a `docker` zone to which the `docker0` and `docker_gwbridge` interfaces are assigned.

```xml
$ cat /etc/firewalld/zones/docker.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone version="1.0" target="ACCEPT">
  <short>docker</short>
  <description>zone for docker bridge network interfaces</description>
  <interface name="docker_gwbridge"/>
  <interface name="docker0"/>
</zone>
```

After reboot, or `firewalld` restart or reload, these interfaces appear in the correct zone, per `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones`.

```bash
$ firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
docker
  interfaces: docker_gwbridge docker0
internal
  interfaces: vethb6daacd veth0a3a13c veth3922477 veth1fc2c24 veth35f6f77 veth172d461 vethf457e97 vethed46b94 vethc3293eb vethe6c08de vethb1c5fb6 vethd6bcfd8 eth0
```

However, after some minutes (usually less than an hour), they move to `internal` zone instead, breaking networking in containers.

```bash
$ firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
internal
  interfaces: vethb6daacd veth0a3a13c veth3922477 veth1fc2c24 veth35f6f77 veth172d461 vethf457e97 vethed46b94 vethc3293eb vethe6c08de vethb1c5fb6 vethd6bcfd8 eth0 docker_gwbridge docker0 veth5686e56 vetha51060c vethde79c75
```

A `firewall-cmd --reload` fixes it again for a little while.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/819143/cant-keep-interfaces-in-assigned-zones-centos7) looked relevant, but these interfaces (if I'm interpreting correctly) are not managed by NetworkManager, so I don't think that's at fault.

```bash
$ nmcli device
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION
eth0             ethernet  connected               eth0
docker0          bridge    connected (externally)  docker0
docker_gwbridge  bridge    connected (externally)  docker_gwbridge
veth5686e56      ethernet  unmanaged               --
vetha51060c      ethernet  unmanaged               --
vethde79c75      ethernet  unmanaged               --
lo               loopback  unmanaged               --

$ ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
ifcfg-eth0
```

I can't find anything interesting in `/var/log/firewalld`. I have several other nodes that are theoretically configured the same way where this problem doesn't occur.

I didn't set the nodes up, and I'm not a sysadmin, but I'm trying to figure it out! Any words of wisdom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a Chef task is the cause of this, with Chef inexplicably configured differently between working and broken servers.